# How can I make my Excel add-in execute a function whenever the document opens?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

There is a [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/run-code-on-document-open) in the documentation which says to use `Office.addin.setStartupBehavior(Office.StartupBehavior.load);` to make an add-in load when a document opens. However, where in my project should I call this? I've tried putting it in `./src/functions/functions.js`, `./src/commands/commands.js`, and `./src/taskpane/taskpane.js`. However, it never seems to be executed since calling `let  behavior = await Office.addin.getStartupBehavior();` yields `none`. Moreover, the following in my `./src/commands/commands.js` is never executed:

```js
Office.onReadt(async () => {
  let context = new Excel.RequestContext();
  context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet().name = "test";
  await context.sync();
});
```